# Is it possible to have dynamic images within a email?

Tags: email, html-email

Is it possible to have images which will change dynamically over time? For example, on a email I have one image which I need displayed when a support team is offline and an other image displayed when the support team is online. Is this possible? If so how?

Could it be as simple as having one image URL inserted into the email which the URL image changes at certain points of the day?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that this way, whoever opened that email and has it open will still see the old image.

But besides that, it seems very reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

It is very possible. You can create a PHP page that generates an image. Something similar to the code below:

```
<?php

header("Content-type: image/png");
$string = $_GET['text'];
$im     = imagecreatefrompng("images/button1.png");
$orange = imagecolorallocate($im, 220, 210, 60);
$px     = (imagesx($im) - 7.5 * strlen($string)) / 2;
imagestring($im, 3, $px, 9, $string, $orange);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);

?>
```

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/image.examples-png.php)

For time of day you can add timezone as a PHP variable. Now after the timezone you can display different things using PHP if statements.